# C++ Multithreading vs Python and the GIL

Tags: python, c++, multithreading

I have several questions about how multithreading is handled in C++. It is known that in Python, thanks to the GIL, having multiple threads running at the "same time" is not truly correct. Only one thread can execute an action at the time. Is this the case with C++? If I use multithreading in C++ is it really simultaneously multithreaded? Can I have multiple threads really running at the same time?.

The other question is that, if I wrote a function in C++, say it is using multiple threads, and I wrap it to use it in Python, is the execution flow and performance of the function written in C++ affected by the GIL? How is this process handled behind the scenes? Will the threads initiated in the C++ function be affected by the Python GIL?

Also, is there any equivalent in C++ for the multiprocessing library in Python? Or all of this could be handled by the use of threads? Thanks in advance.

Parallelism and simultaneously multithreaded apps in C++ vs Python.

Comment: There are no GIL pretty much in any language other than python, which is the odd one out.

Comment: In C++ it depends on how many simultaneous threads the hardware (and underlying system software) can support. If the answer is one thread, you're in the same boat.

Comment: There are many libraries for parallel computation in C++. It is something C++ excels at. One such library is Intel oneTBB, which makes parallel loops and reductions easy. And yes, perf-orients C++ programmers are sad when even one core is idle. :-)

Comment: @PasserBy: To be clear, the GIL is not part of Python-the-language, it's an implementation detail of CPython, the reference interpreter (one which PyPy also suffers from). Other Python interpreters don't have to have it (e.g. neither Jython nor IronPython have one), as nothing in the language requires it to exist.

Comment: "Will the threads initiated in the C++ function be affected by the Python GIL?" -- the GIL doesn't "affect threads". It serializes the access to Python interpreter. If the C++ code in question doesn't **call** Python code, this is not an issue.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, Re, "the GIL is not part of Python-the-language." If _only..._ People have been trying to remove the GIL from Python for more than twenty years. The problem is, while the GIL itself is not part of the language specification, its existence allows Python to have a simplistic [_memory model_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_(programming)). Naive attempts to remove the GIL end up changing the memory model, and breaking existing, multi-threaded programs. Attempts to remove it while preserving the memory model end up making even single-threaded programs run more slowly.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: I'm well aware of all those issues. None of that has *anything* to do with Python-the-language (as in the language spec that anyone can write an interpreter for), they're issues with the CPython reference interpreter, and any alternate interpreter that tries to remain compatible with it for C extensions (PyPy). Your comment reads like a correction to something I never said.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I'm not trying to put words in your mouth. I'm saying that the GIL really is part of the languge. Anything that you can't change in the _reference_ interpreter without breaking existing programs is part of the language.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: And you're *wrong*. The reference interpreter has historical kruft, and the GIL is part of that. Python, as a language, has been reimplemented multiple times with no GIL. It's a CPython (and PyPy) implementation detail (an important one, that has shaped the design of the language, e.g. in making multiprocessing more important due to threading being unsuitable for CPU bound work on CPython), not something the language requires, period. Saying it's "part of the language" is 100% wrong when IronPython and Jython exist as implementations of the Python language without a GIL.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, Yes. It's krufty. But any implementation of the Python language that does not behave like the reference implementation is not a correct implementation. That's what "reference" means. (At least, that's what my co-workers and my bosses at IBM told me when I used to work there.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow: You really don't understand what the language specification means, do you? Your bosses were *wrong*. If it's not in the spec, or that part of the spec is marked as a CPython implementation detail, an alternate implementation isn't required to do it. Reference implementation just means "example adhering to the spec", it doesn't mean it can't do beyond the spec that don't violate the spec. The GIL is *not* part of the spec, and you're being willfully ignorant by saying it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250265/discussion-between-shadowranger-and-solomon-slow).